# DNS protocol rfc1035

Tags: node.js, dns, rfc

i learn javascript on node.js, and i want write dns cache server.
but i have some problem to understand the answer section of protocol
(rfc1035. 4.1.3. Resource record format)

i painted a header and question section of protocol 
(rfc1035. 4.1.2. Question section format) https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JWBL.png

can any one help me understand "resource record format", mb link to a more friendlier interpretation, or piece of code in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Check out [node-dns](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns) module ([here is](https://github.com/tjfontaine/native-dns-packet/blob/master/packet.js#L507) resource record parser)